# Interpreting Input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I made some HTML code in [replit.com](https://replit.com).

Please excuse me if the question I ask is very dumb, since I am new to HTML & JS.

I want the user to type something in the input field and click the "Click Me" button.
I expected the button to change its text to whatever the user typed. But instead, it just went blank.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="text">Type Some Text:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="type" name="text"><br><br>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: khaki; margin-left: 20px; padding-left: 30px; border: solid 5px; border-radius: 40px; padding-right: 450px; font-size: 18px" onclick="Click()" id="click">Click Me!</button>
    <script>
      function Click() {
        text = document.getElementById("type").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = text;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `.value` to get the value of an input, not `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you! Its working now! Please put this in the answer so I can mark you ;)

Comment: I generally don't bother posting answers for trivial mistakes like this. I just vote to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/jacobcambell/pen/OJjyoWW

A few things to consider here.

First, to get the value of an HTML input, you need to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`, for example:

```
text = document.getElementById("type").value;
```

Next, (optionally) you can just call `alert()` instead of `window.alert()` as most browsers know how to handle it correctly.

Finally, to change your button, you need to set the innerHTML of the button to your `text` variable, right now you're just setting it equal to `"text"` which is a `string` in JavaScript. You are literally making your button say "text"

Also, I would recommend using `let` to declare your variables here.

A final version of your `Click` function might look like:

```js
function Click() {
    let text = document.getElementById("type").value;
    alert(text)
    document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
function Click() {
        text = document.getElementById("type").value;
        document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = text;
      }
```

Also, you can also use this:

```js
function Click() {
        document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = document.getElementById("type").value
}
```